# How to track a variable in Eclipse without compiling the code?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to follow a variable through different functions in Eclipse. But using "Open declaration" for each function is time consuming.

Is there a call flow option? Where a nice graph is presented with the variable of interest.

Comment: You can search for the variable. If it is a private or local variable, then put the mouse pointer on it and hit the keyboard keys control, shift, U at the same time. The search results will show all the lines of code containing that variable. If the variable is package private or protected or public, use control, shift, G